# Dereferencing the incremented array of char pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

The second argument to the `main` function is an array of char pointers, and it is possible to do something like `printf("%s", *++argv);` on it to print the first argument to the program. Why can't I do the same thing with a self-made array of char-pointers, upon which I get the error:

```
gcc q.c
q.c: In function ‘main’:
q.c:8:17: error: lvalue required as increment operand
   printf("%s", *++a);
                 ^~
```

The program looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char *a[] = {"Hello world", "c", "programming"};
  printf("%s", *++a);
  printf("%s", *++argv);
    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers, and pointers are not arrays. Therefore you can't do things to arrays that you can do with pointers, like for example increasing them.

Comment: As for `++argv` it's because for all arguments using the "array" declaration syntax, it's really a pointer. So the argument declaration `char *argv[]` is really the same as `char **argv`. Meaning `argv` is a pointer which you can increment.

Comment: So my example doesn't work because I explicitly have initialized it with an array?

Comment: @Student: Your `++a` does not work because `a` **is** an array. The initializers do not change the type (except they could affect the size); the fact it is declared with `char *a[]` makes it an array.

Comment: @Daij-Djan No `a[0] == &a` is not the same. `&a[0] == &a` happens to be the same, but they have very different types. And `&a[1] == &a+1` is even more wrong.

Comment: 1 is sizeof(a) to make sense but sorry - my bad. removed my comment - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays degenerate to pointers when passed to other functions (`main` or whatever). Since `argv` (array of strings) actually degenerated to `char **`, it gave the expected answer for the statements like `printf("%s", *++argv);`. Please remember that it happens only for passing arrays around to functions. If you pass your own `char *a[]` to any other function, it'll also behave the same (ie. degenerates to `char**`). But within the scope of the array declaration, the array won't degenerate to a pointer and it's not even an lvalue to change increment/decrement it.

Answer (score 0):

In `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, `argv` is not really an array. Because you cannot pass arrays as arguments, or receive them as parameters, the compiler automatically adjusts the declaration so that `argv` is a pointer instead of an array, as if the declaration said `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. This automatic adjustment only occurs for declarations of function parameters.

Then, when `++argv` is evaluated, it increments the pointer.

Since your `a` is an array, it cannot be incremented.

You could instead define `a` to be a pointer:

```
char **a = (char *[]) { "Hello world", "c", "programming" };
```

Then you can use `printf("%s", *++a);`.

(The source code `(char *[]) { "Hello world", "c", "programming" }` is a *compound literal* that creates an array of pointers to `char` and initializes the array using the strings, each of which the compiler converts to a pointer to the first character of the string. Then `a` is initialized to point to the first element of this array.)

Comment: I guess that you meant `char **argv` instead of `char *argv[]` in "so that `argv` is a pointer instead of an array, as if the declaration said `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`".